# Where is the code that manages View re-use in Android?

Tags: java, view, android

Where is the source code that manages `View` re-use in Android? I can think of three distinct parts to this process, but there may be more:

1. The logic that determines if a `View` is eligible for re-use
2. The code that manages pools of `View`s that can be re-used
3. The code that removes a re-usable `View` from the pool and resets its property values to represent a logically different `View`

**EDIT:** The blog post [Developing applications for Android – gotchas and quirks](https://jonhoo.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/developing-applications-for-android-gotchas-and-quirks/) gives the following example:

```
public class PencilWise extends ListActivity {
    View activeElement;
    // ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        // ...
        this.getListView( ).setOnItemClickListener ( new OnItemClickListener ( ) {
            public void onItemClick ( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) {
                MyActivity.this.activeElement = view;
                MyActivity.this.showDialog ( DIALOG_ANSWER );
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

> The `showDialog` method will display the answer dialog, which needs to know what question the user has opened. The problem is that by the time the dialog opens, the view passed to `onItemClick` might have been reused, and so `activeElement` would no longer point to the element the user clicked to open the dialog in the first place!

Comment: For places that need View reuse Android usually has some infrastructure in place to assist with this. An example is when using AdapterViews/Adapter such as a ListView with BaseAdapter. Other than that I'm not sure what is really being asked here.

Comment: @Jeremy: See [https://jonhoo.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/developing-applications-for-android-gotchas-and-quirks/](https://jonhoo.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/developing-applications-for-android-gotchas-and-quirks/). I wasn't clear, but I am not talking about, for example, the ability of `Adapter` implementations to reuse a list item view by checking if the `convertView` parameter to [`getView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) is non-`null`. I am talking about the view re-use that is built-in somehow.

Comment: @Jeremy: I imagine that this code is somewhere within [platform/frameworks/base](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=summary), but I don't know where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good example of what you're looking for is in the `AbsListView.RecycleBin` inner class located in the `widget` package.
You can see the code online here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-2.2_r1.1/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java#3888

Here's an excerpt from the documentation:

> The RecycleBin facilitates reuse of views across layouts. The RecycleBin has two levels of
>     storage: ActiveViews and ScrapViews. ActiveViews are those views which were onscreen at the
>     start of a layout. By construction, they are displaying current information. At the end of
>     layout, all views in ActiveViews are demoted to ScrapViews. ScrapViews are old views that
>     could potentially be used by the adapter to avoid allocating views unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3):

Views recycling is performed by `AbsListView` and their subclasses `ListView` and `GridView`. You can find the source code of these classes here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget

Start with `ListView` and `AbsListView`.